# Combining 100+ Materials

Tags: mesh, materials, baking

So I have a mesh model obtained from google maps data and we are using it for large-scale site representation. We typically combine architectural models with this google maps data and put up on sketchfab. However, Sketchfab only takes max 100 materials and my current model is sitting around 300. Is there a way to combine these materials? I dont have to combine all of them into one massive texture as long as i can get the materials number below 100. I saw that people bake these combined materials onto a single map but i tried and have crashed out my computer numerous times. My rig is i9 GTX 3090TI with 128gb ram so i don't think getting a beefier computer is a solution.
Any help or advice is welcome :) See below some images of the project.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a bit old but i did find a solution to this question.
Nicko16 made a great tutorial for this exact task that can be found here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUkMY8Sp_AM&t=202s&ab_channel=Nicko16
Another is to get Eliemichels texture pack which packs all the textures into one single image thus one single material. Literally saved me hours and hours to manually re-map and rebake. Here is the texture pack:
https://eliemichel.gumroad.com/l/DFExj Go and give them a follow/ donate and hope its helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion is you could bake some of these maps to a single texture and apply the same texture to multiple objects. Only issue here is that you would have to UV Unwrap *everything*, which is a killer task with a scene as dense as this one. If you are interested in the baking process, Grant Abbitt has a pretty straight-forward [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH7Xdol5erw) for this.